# How to replace backslashes with forward slashes without changing the content of the link

Tags: php, regex, escaping

There is an old question from 2011 but with a wrong answer.

Maybe now someone can give a better answer. The question was: How can we replace the backslashes with forward slashes from this variable-link:

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif";
```

The wrong answer was that:

```
echo $str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

And it was wrong because the result of that code changes the content of the link. (`http://www.domain.com/data/imageslags/en.gif`)
It finds not only the backslash but the letter f after that and it deletes them because `\f` means "`formfeed (hex 0C)`". So how can we avoid this wrong replacement?

[The Code is here](http://rextester.com/ZXFT9116)

Comment: first of all, who has form feed in urls?

Comment: can you just use single quotes for $str? I think this should work

Comment: I think it doesn't matter

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: ´http://www.domain.com/data/images/flags/en.gif`

Comment: @sotirios: I does matter because, when you use single quotes the string is not processed, so \f is just \f, you can try it in the code link above

Comment: Have a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/FE41Fm), is it what you are after?

Comment: Hi, @stribizhev  your code changes \flags to /lags too. :(

Comment: Yes, because `\f` is a line feed. And it is part of whitespace that is matched with `\s`. You cannot tore apart one character. Or you will have to use [this replacement](http://ideone.com/5s8tz3).

Comment: And If I don't know what the next character of backslash is, what can I do? Maybe somewhere else is \e or \n. should I do the same for all?

Comment: Maybe [this code](http://ideone.com/KcpGGq) will work for your requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I change the link to `http://www.domain.com/data/images\elags/en.gif` then I get `http://www.domain.com/data/images/033lags/en.gif`

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif";
echo $str = str_replace('lags', "/flags", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) but you'll have to specify each possible escaped character that could occur in `$str`

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif";
$escaped = str_replace("\\","/",addcslashes($str,"\f\r\n\t"));
echo $escaped; // result is 'http://www.domain.com/data/images/flags/en.gif'
```